# How do I pass a string into Ant java? Somehow my program does not take arguments with white spaces

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to get a string to be passed into ant in order for it to be ran as a parameter inside of a java function. Does anyone know how to do this?

Defining a string, this string has to have white spaces in between. For example, "Hello world hi"

```
    <target name = "run" depends="compile">
            <property name="input" value="report" />
            <java classname="assn4">
                    <classpath>
                            <pathelement path="."/>
                    </classpath>
                    <arg line="${input}"/>
            </java>
    </target>
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate?!

Comment: @KhoiTran if it's not a duplicate, then please edit your question to clarify exactly what you're after, and why it's _not_ the same thing as in that other question.

Comment: In the other solution, the function call allows for strings that are not separated by white space. ant -Darg0=Hello -Darg1=World run. However, the implementation I want can be separated by white space: ant -Darg0="Hello john" -Darg1="World of cheese" run

Comment: So, doesn't quoting work?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't. Yeah I am not sure why it is not working. I posted the code and changed the question. So at this point, I am assuming that the other code does work with quotes and somehow mines doesn't.

Comment: I don't know if quoting works or not but in my program it is not working and I believe I use the same method as described in the other thread.

Comment: Do you want to pass argument to main method of class assn4? See if this helps http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_executing_java_code.htm

Comment: Yes, I want to pass a string with spaces into the main method of assn4. The String can be of variable length and has a variable amount of white spaces.

Comment: Please see this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_executing_java_code.htm

Comment: I read that, the string that they have is hard coded. I need to be able to run ant and send the argument through there.

Comment: @KhoiTran, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028083/java-ant-passing-whole-argument-line-to-ant-and-to-program --appears same as this?

Comment: It is the same because it was made by me. I accidentally double clicked too fast and it made two? I have no idea how that happened.

Comment: @KhoiTran, can you tell what is happening?

Comment: The string that they have in their example in the link you gave me is hard coded. Even more, that string doesn't even contain spaces.

Comment: @KhoiTran, that is ok. But what is happening when you run your target with spaces in the string? try running `ant -debug`.

Comment: nvm I got it. Sorry about that. I wasn't using the run target.

Comment: Not sure how to end this thread since it was a silly and not enlightening discovery.

Comment: @KhoiTran, The simple problem you have is: change from <arg line="some value"> to <arg value="some value">. Also added the complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete working example.

**Test.java**

```java
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String userString = args[0];      
      System.out.println("*****"+ userString+"*****");
   }
}
```

**build.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample" basedir="." default="testJavaArgument">
   <target name="testJavaArgument">
      <java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="Test">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="."/>
        </classpath>
         <arg value="Hello World!"/>
      </java>
   </target>
</project>
```

**Output**

```
testJavaArgument:
     [java] *****Hello World!*****

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

The simple problem you have is: change from `<arg line="some value">` to `<arg value="some value">`